# Sample Google endpoints client for C#

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I followed the example for creating google endpoints, and I can see that they work properly in the apis explorer. I then generated the C# library using the google-apis-client-generator python script, and after a bit of tweaking it builds properly. Does anyone have a sample C# project that utilizes the generated library? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This endpoints sample might help you:
https://github.com/peleyal/peleyal/tree/master/TicTacToe

More documentation about the .NET client library for Google APIs is available at: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/

Our samples are available at: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples

What else? :)